# Error while inserting into database c#, Data Conversion Failed

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

While trying to do an insert statement into my table, I get this error:

> Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]

I have done my research online and seem to not be able to find an answer to solve this problem.

The insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Beverages] (BeverageID, ParentBeverageID, Name, PreferredRecipeVersion, 
                         SpecificCustomerID, AcceptabilityRating, ShowBeverage, Availability, 
                         Family, EngagedPriority, SmilePriority, Collections) 
VALUES (1475614, 1475633, 'Caffeine-free', 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'A', 'NULL', 1, 'UK')
```

My initial build of the table (which does create it) looks like this:

```
string beverages = "CREATE TABLE [Beverages]([BeverageID] INT NOT NULL,[ParentBeverageID] INT, [Name] NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,[PreferredRecipeVersion] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),[SpecificCustomerID] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),[AcceptabilityRating] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),[ShowBeverage] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),[Availability] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),[Family] NVARCHAR(1),[EngagedPriority] INT,[SmilePriority] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0), [Collections] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);";
string beverages1 = "ALTER TABLE [Beverages] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__Beverages__000000000000134A] PRIMARY KEY ([BeverageID]);";
string beverages2 = "CREATE INDEX [PK_BeverageID] ON [Beverages] ([BeverageID] ASC);";
db.ExecuteSqlCommand(beverages, null, __gulfstreamDataConn);
db.ExecuteSqlCommand(beverages1, null, __gulfstreamDataConn);
db.ExecuteSqlCommand(beverages2, null, __gulfstreamDataConn);
```

I don't know what would be causing this issue, but thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: EngagedPriority is INT, but you sent a varchar 'NULL'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the field **EngagedPriority** to NULL you should write NULL without the single quotes. Using the quotes around the word NULL confuses the parser to recognize the value  as a string but the field **EngagedPriority** is an Int....

```
 string beverages = "CREATE TABLE [Beverages]([BeverageID] INT NOT NULL," + 
                    "[ParentBeverageID] INT, [Name] NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL," + 
                    "[PreferredRecipeVersion] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)," + 
                    "[SpecificCustomerID] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)," + 
                    "[AcceptabilityRating] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)," + 
                    "[ShowBeverage] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)," + 
                    "[Availability] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)," + 
                    "[Family] NVARCHAR(1)," + 
                -->>"[EngagedPriority] INT," + 
                    "[SmilePriority] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0), " + 
                    "[Collections] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);";


  "INSERT INTO [Beverages] (BeverageID, ParentBeverageID, Name, PreferredRecipeVersion," + 
  "SpecificCustomerID, AcceptabilityRating, ShowBeverage, Availability, Family," +
  "EngagedPriority, SmilePriority, Collections) " + 
  "Values (1475614,1475633,'Caffeine-free ',3,1,0,1,1,'A',NULL,1,'UK')
                                                          ^^^^
```

Comment: Could you do a replace? like string x = y.replace("'NULL'", null); ?

Comment: It depends on how do you prepare the command text. In the example every field is directly set to its value. If you need to pass values from the input then you need to use parameters and you set the appropriate parameter to DBNull.Value

Comment: How would DBNull.Value work? I understand that it is a null for databases, but say that the input was actually a Varchar instead of an int? for instance, x.replace("'NULL'", DBNull.value) actually does not work

Comment: No, DBNull.Value is used with a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) not with textual command like this. (By the way use always a parameterized query) However, without knowing more of your context is not possible to give a sound advice on this

Answer (score 0):

Null is `NULL` not `'NULL'` -- remove the single quotes from the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are inserting 'NULL' instead of NULL. When you use 'NULL' SQL takes that as a VarChar. NULL (no quotes) will give you the answer you are looking for.